# Site URL is not redirecting correctly

Tags: posts

I have changed the site URL and home URL in the settings. When I click any page on my website, it is not redirecting properly. If I put the IP address in the place of site URL it is working properly. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

use [search and replace db](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) file and replace all your ip address to your domain name

Comment: It is pointing to the core files residing IP